# Chromium doesn't shutdown correctly with 2 or more active tabs open (18.04)

Tags: command-line, shutdown, chromium

Whenever I **shutdown or reboot or logout** of my computer with Chromium running at least 2 active tabs, the next time I **launch Chromium** I get the following **error**:

[image]

**This error happens if I shutdown or reboot or logout from the UI or from a terminal.**

I'm using Chromium: "Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)"
But I've had the same issue with previous versions of Chromium and Ubuntu.

Just for clarity, if I quit/close Chromium running multiple tabs directly from the application, no such error occurs.

Is this expected behaviour or is something misconfigured?

Comment: Is the command run like this `shutdown now` or just `shutdown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal and expected behavior of a browser ...

> if I quite/close Chromium running multiple tabs directly from the application, no such error occurs.

You have to close your browser before you shutdown/reboot your system. otherwise before system getting shutdown a signal will be sent to all running programs (process) (chromium in our case) asking the process to close itself.

That causes chromium to immediately close itself (seems not being shutdown properly) and thus the session (more than of one tab) being lost, so next time when you run chromium it suggests you to restore the lost session (it considers that system has crashed or you have encounter a power failure, etc).

---

Test it without shutdown:

1. open chromium
2. open two or more tabs
3. open a new terminal
4. run this command:

   ```
   pkill -3 chromium
   ```
5. open chromium again

Same message will be appeared...

Comment: Thank you... I have a follow up question which I'll ask in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium processes do not completely exit, if you close it with the window icon. That's why those leftover processes get the kill signal on OS shutdown. If you choose Exit from the menu, *all* chromium processes exit. 
The question here is why the behavior differs if you exit Chromium via icon versus menu.